# Algebra Identity $(A - B)(A^2 + AB + B^2) = A^3 - B^3$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I have the following problem:

$$\frac{(x^2 - 2x)^\frac{1}{3} - 2}{x^2 - 2x - 8}$$

It is solved by using the identity $(A - B)(A^2 + AB + B^2) = A^3 - B^3$ and multiplying the problem by
$$\frac{(x^2 - 2x)^\frac{2}{3} + 2(x^2 - 2x)^\frac{1}{3} +4}{(x^2 - 2x)^\frac{2}{3} + 2(x^2 - 2x)^\frac{1}{3} +4} $$

But I do not understand how the identity equates to $(x^2 - 2x)^\frac{2}{3} + 2(x^2 - 2x)^\frac{1}{3} +4$

Comment: The numerator of the problem is of the form, $A-B$. The thing you multiply by involves $A^2+AB+B^2$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If we set $$A=(x^2 - 2x)^\frac{1}{3},~ B=2$$ then $$A^2+AB+B^2=\left((x^2 - 2x)^\frac{1}{3}\right)^{\color{red}{2}}+(x^2 - 2x)^\frac{1}{3}\times(2)+(2)^4=(x^2 - 2x)^\frac{\color{red}{2}}{3}+2(x^2 - 2x)^\frac{1}{3}+4$$